# access to data allocated by pointer in a structure issue

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I'm working on code that using structures and Linked list.
Please help me to understand how can I print any added point that is not in the head of the list created.
Any attempt was a failure.

*Issue on the second print call.

Is my only option is to do head = head->next in order to get the next variables?
Structures:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}point;

typedef struct {
    point *p;
    struct Item *next;
}Item;
```

Main:

```
void main()
{   
    Item *head = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item)); //head of co-list
    if (!head) { //allocation check
        printf("Allocation failed (head)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    head = addBegin(head);
    printf("head point: (%d,%d)\n",head->p->x,head->p->y);
    system("pause");
    head = addBegin(head);
    **printf("head second point: (%d,%d)\n",head->next->p->x,head->next->p->y);**
    system("pause");
    free(head->p);
    free(head);
}
```

The function:

```
Item * addBegin(Item *head)
{
    Item *tmp = (Item*)
        malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (tmp) {
        tmp->p = (point*)malloc(sizeof(point));
        printf("Enter x's point: ");
        scanf(" %d", &tmp->p->x);
        printf("Enter y's point: ");
        scanf(" %d", &tmp->p->y);
        tmp->next = head;
        return tmp;
    }
    else{        //memory allocation failed
        printf("allocation failed (new head)\n");
        exit(2);
        return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to walk the list, with code similar to:

```
for ( Item* current = &head;
      current != NULL;
      current = current->next ) {
  do_stuff_with(current->p);
}
```

This stops when you reach the end of the list: that is, when you have processed the last node containing data, whose `next` pointer is `NULL`, and updated `current` to `NULL`.

On a side note, you want to tweak the definition of `Item` slightly, to:

```
typedef struct Item {
    point *p;
    struct Item *next;
} Item;
```

Some compilers, including GCC, will realize that `Item.next` has the same type, and stop giving you spurious warnings about anonymous structs and incomplete types.

it might also pay to decide whether you want to use `Item` and `Point`, or `item` and `point`.  Inconsistent capitalization is confusing.